# uploading image to s3 using carrierwave and fogs bad uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fog

Hi I'm trying to upload some images on s3 using fogs and carrierwave. Before I did it in my public folders and I'd like to make it on a bucket. When I'm trying to uploads a new picture I get :
`URI::InvalidURIError` in `EventsController create` bad URI(is not URI?)

I've made some research and that could come from a "+" symbol in the name but I don't have any "+"
here is my parameters request:

```
> {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"ms48hFw8dTALEe543dPS0ywIdKynYvuAHMjiry7kghQ=",
 "event"=>{"titre"=>"test des image avec S3",
 "dday(1i)"=>"2013",
 "dday(2i)"=>"3",
 "dday(3i)"=>"30",
 "lieux"=>"maison",
 "commentaire"=>"aucune",
 "pictures_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"test",
 "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xa35a14c @original_filename="image.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"event[pictures_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
 @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20130330-26465-11z9gsf>>}}},
 "commit"=>"Ajouter"}
```

I've followed the indication from https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave
here is some code

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
        :provider               => 'AWS',                        # required
        :aws_access_key_id      => 'xxx',                        # required
        :aws_secret_access_key  => 'xxx',                        # required
        :region                 => 'eu-west-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
        :host                   => 'xxx.com',             # optional, defaults to nil
        :endpoint               => '' # optional, defaults to nil
    }
    config.fog_directory  = 'socialmausoleum'                     # required
    config.fog_public     = true                                  # optional, defaults to true
    config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

and my uploader:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Include the Sprockets helpers for Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  # include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  # include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

Thanks for your answears.

Comment: please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shot in the dark

```
:endpoint               => '' # optional, defaults to nil
```

nil ≠ ''

So just remove the whole lin and see what happens. What I think is happening is it is trying to append an empty string to the end of something ending up with a '+' followed by nothing.

Edit:

From their docs

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                        # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'xxx',                        # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'yyy',                        # required
    :region                 => 'eu-west-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
    :host                   => 's3.example.com',             # optional, defaults to nil
    :endpoint               => 'https://s3.example.com:8080' # optional, defaults to nil
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'name_of_directory'                     # required
  config.fog_public     = false                                   # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

In your case you are going to need region I believe to match, but I don't think your going to need host or endpoint.

Comment: Now i Get this error: Excon::Errors::SocketError in EventsController#create

hostname does not match the server certificate

Comment: From what I can see I don't think you need to declare the host either, try removing that also.

Comment: I've remove region host and enpoind and it's now working :) thanks a lot